# how to remove "-" and "/" characters from excel sheet

Tags: excel

I want to remove "-" and "/" from 011-2729729 011/2729729 these numbers and  convert them in to 0112729729 in excel. I tried with substitute function but i could not get the correct answer.

Already attempted formula: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/"," ",4)`

Comment: Can you show the formula you tried?

Comment: =SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/"," ",4)

Comment: Can you have "/" and "-" both in the same string?

Comment: There can be. But I want to remove them only if they are in "4th position".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you truly desire a formula over a macro use this, else Gary's Student provided a nice macro.

If you are specifically searching position **4** then use `REPLACE` not `SUBSTITUTE` with a simple `IF` check at the start to see if position 4 is a "/" or "-"

```
=IF(OR(MID(A1,4,1)="/",MID(A1,4,1)="-"),REPLACE(A1,4,1,""),A1)
```

Notes:

- `SUBSTITUTE` is great when you want to replace certain text with other text
- `REPLACE` is great when you want to replace a certain position with other text

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes removing "/" and "-" will create a string that Excel will treat as a number and you can lose leading zeros.  This small macro will fix the cells "in place"

```
Sub FixValues()
   Dim r As Range, v As String

   For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
      v = r.Text
      If InStr(v, "-") > 0 Or InStr(v, "/") > 0 Then
         r.NumberFormat = "@"
         r.Value = Replace(Replace(v, "-", ""), "/", "")
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: thanx for the answer. But i 'm searing for a single line excel function bcz there are more than 75000 data to sort out.

Comment: @kamaldesilva  After the macro has been installed, running it will  fix all your cells at once.